# Bring an expression to the logarithm convenient state

Tags: trigonometry

My goal is to simplify an expression as much as possible. Here is it:
[image]

It's evident for me that the first step is to split it into two groups - the first one with whole and the second with fractional members, so

$\sin7\alpha - \sin5\alpha - \sin9\alpha = \sin7\alpha - 2\sin7\alpha\cos2\alpha$

like this and the second group results in:

$-\frac 13 \sin3\alpha\cos6\alpha$

but the solution for this says it should look like this

[image]

what's an evident step i'm missing and stalled with.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: factorizing i have got $$\sin(x)(-2\cos(2x)+2\cos(6x)-1)$$